# logical calculation of Integer interval

Tags: math, intervals

what are the rules to calculate logical op. (AND OR XOR) of two integer intervals ?

Given two intervals [a,b] [c,d] i want to calculate [a,b] xor [c,d]

I assume the result to be multiple ranges

I looked at filib++ and read WIKI but found just Arithmetic op. support

Can anyone educate me

Comment: if range #1 is [1,7] and #2 is [3,3] and you OR them, you get [3,3] and [7,7] not their union

Comment: If you compute the result of `[0, 0xFFFFFFFF] & [0xFFFFFFFE, 0xFFFFFFFE]` as multiple ranges, the ranges you will get will occupy 16 GiB of memory (representing a range as a 32-bit min and a 32-bit max, assuming the most compact representation for sets of ranges). Are you sure this is what you want, or are there some contraints on the inputs you did not tell us about that make the “result as multiple range” tractable in your usecase?

Comment: you are right. i wrote this example to demonstrate that xor was not simple union. in my case i am going to pick one range which does not conflict with other constraints

Comment: In this case my answer may not be useful to you, as it computes a result as an over-approximated interval, any individual value of which does not have to be obtainable as the result of op between a value of the first interval and a value of the second interval.

Answer (score 0):

You can find an implementation of “bitwise and”, “bitwise xor” and “bitwise or” between intervals in the latest version of [Frama-C](http://frama-c.com/download.html), in file src/ai/ival.ml. In fact these functions operate on values of type `Ival.t`, which represent either a small set of integer values, an interval with congruence information or a floating-point interval. You will only be interested in the case `Top _, Top _` (which corresponds to the integer intervals with congruence information). The function compute the result as an `Ival.t`, possibly over-approximated, but which contains all the values x op y with x in the first interval and y in the second interval.

As the comment says, the algorithm for `pos_max_land` is optimal for precision but does not have the best complexity with respect to the number of bits of the integers. I only understood this after I was finished with writing the function, and the width of an integer does not go beyond 64 for this usecase, so I didn't bother writing the faster version.

The file src/ai/ival.ml is licensed under the LGPL 2.1. If you do something cool with it, I would be happy to hear about it.

```
(* [different_bits min max] returns an overapproximation of the mask
   of the bits that can be different for different numbers
   in the interval [min]..[max] *)
let different_bits min max =
  let x = Int.logxor min max in
  next_pred_power_of_two x

(* [pos_max_land min1 max1 min2 max2] computes an upper bound for
   [x1 land x2] where [x1] is in [min1]..[max1] and [x2] is in [min2]..[max2].
   Precondition : [min1], [max1], [min2], [max2] must all have the
   same sign.
   Note: the algorithm below is optimal for the problem as stated.
   It is possible to compute this optimal solution faster but it does not
   seem worth the time necessary to think about it as long as integers
   are at most 64-bit. *)
let pos_max_land min1 max1 min2 max2 =
  let x1 = different_bits min1 max1 in
  let x2 = different_bits min2 max2 in
(*      Format.printf "pos_max_land %a %a -> %a |  %a %a -> %a@."
        Int.pretty min1 Int.pretty max1 Int.pretty x1
        Int.pretty min2 Int.pretty max2 Int.pretty x2; *)
  let fold_maxs max1 p f acc =
    let rec aux p acc =
      let p = Int.shift_right p Int.one in
      if Int.is_zero p
      then f max1 acc
      else if Int.is_zero (Int.logand p max1) 
      then aux p acc
      else 
        let c = Int.logor (Int.sub max1 p) (Int.pred p) in
        aux p (f c acc)
    in aux p acc
  in
  let sx1 = Int.succ x1 in
  let n1 = fold_maxs max1 sx1 (fun _ y -> succ y) 0 in
  let maxs1 = Array.make n1 sx1 in
  let _ = fold_maxs max1 sx1 (fun x i -> Array.set maxs1 i x; succ i) 0 in
  fold_maxs max2 (Int.succ x2)
    (fun max2 acc -> 
      Array.fold_left
        (fun acc max1 -> Int.max (Int.logand max1 max2) acc)
        acc
        maxs1)
    (Int.logand max1 max2)

let bitwise_or v1 v2 =
  if is_bottom v1 || is_bottom v2
  then bottom
  else
    match v1, v2 with
      Float _, _ | _, Float _ -> top
     | Set s1, Set s2 ->
        apply2_v Int.logor s1 s2
     | Set s, v | v, Set s when Array.length s = 1 && Int.is_zero s.(0) -> v
     | Top _, _ | _, Top _ ->
         ( match min_and_max v1 with
           Some mn1, Some mx1 when Int.ge mn1 Int.zero ->
             ( match min_and_max v2 with
               Some mn2, Some mx2 when Int.ge mn2 Int.zero ->
                 let new_max = next_pred_power_of_two (Int.logor mx1 mx2) in
                 let new_min = Int.max mn1 mn2 in (* Or can only add bits *)
                 inject_range (Some new_min) (Some new_max)
             | _ -> top )
         | _ -> top )

let bitwise_xor v1 v2 =
  if is_bottom v1 || is_bottom v2
  then bottom
  else
    match v1, v2 with
     | Float _, _ | _, Float _ -> top
     | Set s1, Set s2 -> apply2_v Int.logxor s1 s2
     | Top _, _ | _, Top _ ->
       (match min_and_max v1 with
         | Some mn1, Some mx1 when Int.ge mn1 Int.zero ->
           (match min_and_max v2 with
             | Some mn2, Some mx2 when Int.ge mn2 Int.zero ->
               let new_max = next_pred_power_of_two (Int.logor mx1 mx2) in
               let new_min = Int.zero in
               inject_range (Some new_min) (Some new_max)
             | _ -> top )
         | _ -> top )
```